# Accelerating Z3 solver via OpenMP

Tags: openmp, z3

I have recently started using the Z3 solver (C++ API), and in some cases when using a large number of constrains the run time of the solver can be very long.
I'm running on a Linux system, and noticed that the Z3 solver dynamically links to the OpenMP shared object, so i assume that it uses OpenMP in order to accelerate the solving process.

I have 2 questions regrading this:

1. What parts of the Z3 solver use OpenMP for acceleration?
2. Is there a way to enable acceleration via OpenMP, and if so How?